# Error launching Spyder from Anaconda Navigator - "chcp 1252 ... 1>nul 2>nul"

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am using Anaconda to conduct data analysis in Python using Spyder. I've been doing so with no trouble for while now, installing packages, updating packages/Spyder/etc., but after updating Spyder, I now receive an error message when launching Spyder from within Anaconda.

```
C:\Users\jdoe>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\Users\jdoe>call C:\Users\jdoe\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate C:\Users\jdoe\Anaconda3

(base) C:\Users\jdoe>spyder  1>nul 2>nul
```

This terminal window appears, then closes itself and Spyder along with it.

If I open a terminal window from within Anaconda and type `spyder`, I am able to launch the app successfully. But launching from Anaconda Navigator fails, and I don't understand this error message or how to fix it, nor have I been able to find anything relating to this issue in searching. Any help understanding what is going on and how to correct this would be appreciated.

`conda info` report if useful:

```
(base) C:\Users\jdoe>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\jdoe\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\jdoe\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\jdoe\.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.1
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.8.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\jdoe\Anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\jdoe\Anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\jdoe\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\jdoe\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\jdoe\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\jdoe\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.1 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.8.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```